# Illegal character error when compiling simple hasse algorithm program in java

Tags: java

I cant seem to figure out why the below code won't compile. I get up an error for the line saying: `if ((number % 2) ==  0) {`. The error message says: "illegal character". The program is supposed to take a number n. If the n == to 1, the program stops. If n is odd it, then the new n == (n*3)+1. If n is even, new n == n/2.

```
import java.util.Scanner; 
import java.lang.Math.*; 

public class HasseAlgoritme {

public static void main(string [] args) {
 Scanner tastatur = new Scanner(System.in); 

 System.out.print("Input the first starting number"); 
 int number = tastatur.next(); 

 while (number != 1) { 
  System.out.print(number);        
      if ((number % 2) ==  0) {       
        System.out.println(number);
      }          
      else {
        number = (number*3)+1; 
        System.out.print(number); 
      }              
 } 
}}
```

Comment: can you please reformat this?

Comment: And paste in the *full* error message please.

Comment: Are you sure you quoted the real code?

Answer (score 5):

```
public static void main(string[] args)
```

Should be

```
                        ↓
public static void main(String[] args)
```

Java **is** case sensitive!

Also `number` should be String and not an `int`, this won't compile (or use `nextInt` instead of `next`).

Answer (score 0):

Read integer using this : `int number = tastatur.nextInt();` or 
this : `int number = Integer.parseInt(tastatur.next());`.

Answer (score 0):

If a number is being entered the scanner should use `nextInt()`

```
 int number = tastatur.nextInt();
 tastatur.nextLine();
```

Answer (score 0):

Also `tastatur.next();` returns `String`, you might want to use `tastatur.nextInt();` instead

Answer (score 0):

this will compile.I have closed the scanner. and  You are running infinite while loop

import java.util.Scanner;

```
public class HasseAlgoritme {
    public static void main(String [] args) { 
        Scanner tastatur = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Input the first starting number"); 
        int number = Integer.valueOf(tastatur.next()); 
        while (number != 1) { 
            System.out.print(number);
            if ((number % 2) ==  0) { 
                System.out.println(number);
            }
            else {
                number = (number*3)+1; 
                System.out.print(number); 
            } 
        } 
        tastatur.close();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change `Scanner.next()` to `Scanner.nextInt()`